# QGIS $length returning incorrect values

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

**BACKGROUND:**

At 3.8.3 I have several line shapefiles, each with CRS EPSG:2927.  This is a CRS that I am familiar with, whose units are in feet.

When I use the field calculator with ***$length*** to create a new field containing each record's length the resulting values are in meters (or something close to that), when I was expecting feet.

This looks suspiciously like a CRS issue, but I confirmed the following:

1. All layers really are EPSG:2927
2. I restart QGIS and load just one of the layers.  Project Properties reports EPSG:2927 (plus EPSG:2927 is displayed in the lower-right corner).

Furthermore, if I run the **Add geometry attributes** tool, the results are correctly in feet.  When I use Arc Desktop's (10.7.1) field geometry calculator, the results are identical to the QGIS **Add geometry attributes** tool.

*Finally,* if I use the QGIS field calculator with $length on a meter-based CRS (EPSG:3338) layer, the results are close (within one percent), but not correct.  Again, the **Add geometry attributes** tool creates the meter correct values.

**SUMMARY:**

$length is not generating the correct line lengths.  It appears to ONLY generate output in meters, or something close to that.

In comparison, the QGIS **Add geometry attributes** tool and the Arc Desktop field geometry calculator generate identical correct results, confirmed with the QGIS measuring tool.

Either $length has a bug, or I'm using it incorrectly.  Thoughts?

Comment: Set feet as default units for measurement both in **Project > Properties > General > Measurements** and **Settings > Options > Map Tools > Measure Tool** and try again.

Comment: "The length calculated by this function respects both the current project's ellipsoid setting and distance unit settings. For example, if an ellipsoid has been set for the project then the calculated length will be ellipsoidal, and if no ellipsoid is set then the calculated length will be planimetric." - `$length` function description in QGIS 3.4.

Comment: Thanks to both Leo and csk.  Both of your comments contributed to the differences I was seeing.  Please convert them to answers and I will acknowledge.  My plan going forward is to 1) make sure to set measurements appropriate to the Project CRS, and 2) until I understand the purpose of the Project Properties > General > Ellipsoid setting, leave it at None/Planimetric.  Doing so makes the results equivalent to Arc Desktop geometry field calculator results.  If I can't teach myself this ellipsoid stuff, I will submit a SE question.

Comment: Use `length($geometry)` when you want planimetric lengths and `$length` when you want ellpsoidal ones.