# Problem creating x number of points along geometry in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm relatively new to QGIS, I have past experience with ArcGIS.

I am trying to place 9 equally spaced points along a line, including one at each vertex. The points represent posts along a trellis wire in an orchard.

I have tried both the answers in this post...
[Creating specific amount of points along line in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401226/creating-specific-amount-of-points-along-line-in-qgis)

1. First I used "[Points along geometry](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#points-along-geometry)"; changing the '*Distance*' to `$length/9`
2. Next I used [Geometry By Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) with the following code...

   with_variable (
   'no',
   9,
   collect_geometries (
   array_foreach (
   generate_series (0,@no-1,1),
   line_interpolate_point(
   $geometry,
   length($geometry) / @no * @element
   ))))

My results are that 9 points are placed on each line, with a point on *one* vertex. However, I would like 9 points equally placed on each line with a point on *both* vertices.

[image: Trellis Vectors]
[image: Trellis Vector Attribute Table]
[image: Results]

- QGIS version 3.22.10-Białowieża.
- Windows 10.0.19044 Build 19044
- Project Coordinate Reference System: EPSG: 2927 "NAD83 (HARN) /
  Washington South (ftUS)
- Project Units: Feet
- Layer Coordinate Reference System: Same as the project.

Comment: The vectors were generated from CAD drawing supplied by the architect who designed the orchard.

Comment: related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/338026/qgis-length-returning-incorrect-values

Comment: @JGH From the comments in the post you referenced; I set _feet_ as default units for measurement both in **Project > Properties > General > Measurements** and **Settings > Options > Map Tools > Measure Tool** and tried again. I also tried running **Points Along Geometry** again with `length($geometry) / 9` instead of `length$ / 9`. Last, I changed the **Ellipsoid setting** to **None/Planimetric**... The output is still the same

Comment: With your approach, I assume adding the geometry end_point to the geometry collection would have solved it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this geometry by expression. It will place 9 points along the line length. For some reason I had to subtract 0.0001 or some lines didnt get the end point.

```
collect_geometries(
array_foreach(
generate_series(0, $length, $length/8-0.0001),
line_interpolate_point( $geometry, @element)))
```

[image]

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you. I will do some reading into you solution.