# Creating x number of points along geometry with start and end offsets in QGIS

Tags: qgis

This question is almost identical to [my previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451575/problem-creating-x-number-of-points-along-geometry-in-qgis?noredirect=1#comment737909_451575). However, instead of placing a point *at* each vertex, I would like to place a point at a specified distance from each vertex (start offset, end offset)

For example, I would like 36 points along a group of lines, each with slightly different lengths. The start point and end point is 1.5 feet inward from each line vertex.

I tried using the `Points Along Geometry` tool. With the `Distance` field set to and also `$length/37` and the `Start Offset` and `End Offset` set to `1.5`. All also tried with the `Distance` set to `($length/37)-0.0001`.

[image: Points Along Geometry Output]

I tried `Geometry by Expression` with the expression..

`collect_geometries( array_foreach( generate_series(1.5, $length-1.5, $length/37-0.0001), line_interpolate_point( $geometry, @element)))`

..but was not able to achieve the desired results.

Comment: What was the undesired result that you got?

Comment: I would like the first point on each line and the last point on each line to be the same distance from the vertices of the line. The picture I posted with my question shows that none of the lines meet this criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems in your approach:

1. `$length` calculates ellipsoidal distances. So you might want to use `length($geometry)` to get planimetric distances. *Depending on what CRS you use and what distances you have, that might play a role or not.*
2. Generate a series from 0 to 35 (36 points) and multiply this with the interval. Be aware: there are **35 intervals for 36 points**. So the length of the interval is: line's length minus 3 (for 1.5 offset at start and end), divided by 35. Then add to this the start offset of 1.5 and multiply the `@element` for each point with the interval.

This is the expression to use:

```
collect_geometries( 
    array_foreach( 
        generate_series(0,35), 
        line_interpolate_point ($geometry,1.5+@element*(length($geometry)-3)/35)
    )
)
```

*Demonstration for 26 points and offset of 15 from start-/endpoints:*
[image]

---

Variant:

To easily change the no. of points and the offset, use variables.Change the values of `36` and `1.5` on lines 1 and 2 and the expression will automatically adapt:

```
with_variable('no_of_points',36,  -- change here
with_variable('offset',1.5,  -- change here
collect_geometries( 
    array_foreach( 
        generate_series (0,@no_of_points-1), 
        line_interpolate_point (
            $geometry,
            @offset + @element * (length ($geometry) - 2 * @offset) / (@no_of_points-1))
    )
)))
```

Comment: Wonderful, I understand more now about how the arguments work in this expression. Thank you for the in-depth explanation.